# Testing a class and loading a real object for a dependency instead of mock

Tags: java, spring, junit

I have a Junit unit test which tests a class like below, I want to load a real object for gson and not a mock object, How can I do that using spring ?

```
public class TestA{
public void setUp()
{
A a = new A();
}
}

import javax.inject; 

public class A{
@inject
private Gson gson; 

}
```

I have defined this in my spring-configuration/unit-test-config.xml

```
<bean id="Gson"
          class="com.google.gson.Gson"
          scope="singleton"/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add two annotations to your test class:

```
@Runwith(SpringJunitClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration("classpath:spring-configuration/unit-test-config.xml")
```

The first tells JUnit to use the spring test runner which supports dependency injection and the second registers your XML file to Spring.

You will need the spring-test jar for this, which you can get via maven

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.6.RELEASE</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

But it won't work like that since you create your A object manually. It has to be a spring bean as well.

Comment: So, A has to be a Spring bean too ?

Comment: yes, read more about the topic in here: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html

Comment: Thanks Sean, could you explain why though in short if possible ?

Comment: @Phoenix Spring doesn't know about objects it hasn't created itself. Objects created via `new` are never managed by Spring and hhence can't have dependencies injected.